# activeX exposed methods

Tags: activex

I have a MFC activeX that run fine from local machine but when I'm trying to use when it is on a server (on the LAN) I get exception that the object doesn't have method AboutBox (for example). 
This is how I call the method:
    document.all('Ctrl1').AboutBox();
The method AboutBox is from the activeX's Ctrl class. He has that method. I notice something strange in the idl file though: the method AboutBox is not declared in the control but some where else - the idl file is below, please advice.
Thanks, Nahum.

This is the idl:

```
[ uuid(E0D6BB50-57F3-4C0D-9163-CCC0AEC87EF4), version(1.0),
  control ]
library nsip_ax_10Lib
{
        importlib(STDOLE_TLB);

    //  Primary dispatch interface for Cnsip_ax_10Ctrl
        [ 
            uuid(16C6DE45-B481-4795-AFBA-BE64E1CEF9AA)  
       ]
        dispinterface _Dnsip_ax_10
       {
        properties:
            methods:

                [id(DISPID_ABOUTBOX)] void AboutBox();
                [id(1)] BYTE try2(void);
         };

        //  Event dispatch interface for Cnsip_ax_10Ctrl

       [ 
        uuid(871F4F0A-3333-4FDF-A53F-CFB581D15596)  
       ]
        dispinterface _Dnsip_ax_10Events
       {
          properties:
                //  Event interface has no properties

            methods:
     };

        //  Class information for Cnsip_ax_10Ctrl
       [
           uuid(E228C560-FA68-48E6-850F-B1167515C920)
       ]
     coclass nsip_ax_10
            {
            [default] dispinterface _Dnsip_ax_10;
            [default, source] dispinterface _Dnsip_ax_10Events;
            };

           };
```

---

HTML code for loading the activeX:

```
  <OBJECT CLASSID="CLSID:871F4F0A-3333-4FDF-A53F-CFB581D15596"
        CODEBASE="nsip.CAB#version=1,0,0,1"
        ID="Ctrl1"
        name="Ctrl1"></OBJECT>
```

Comment: The IDL is normal and doesn't explain why your code fails.  Make sure that you don't have an old version of the DLL registered.

Comment: 10xs Hans, the activeX has the method AboutBox since the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

1. The class ID you are using in your Object tag is incorrect:

> **CLASSID="CLSID:871F4F0A-3333-4FDF-A53F-CFB581D15596**"

The ActiveX control class ID is the last one in the IDL file i.e.

```
CLASSID="CLSID:E228C560-FA68-48E6-850F-B1167515C920"
```

2. What I have conceived from code is that your application is not
   pointing to complete server path of CAB file in the object tag.

   ```
   CODEBASE="nsip.CAB"
   ```

   Give the complete path to the ActiveX cab.